# Отпавка сообщений через плагин pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Написал код для бота который будет регистрировать пользователя и после выводить список уже зарегистрированных пользователей при нажатии на кнопку "Список пользователей".
А как сделать так чтобы бот брал отдельную колонку в таблице (sqlite) с названием **phone** и отправлял по этому номеру телефона сообщение в телеграмм (личные сообщения)?

Вот код бота

```py
import telebot
import sqlite3
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('AAEAGNq6xa26V5Vv2GioO85fLYeNcGw1Ya4')

name = None
phone = None


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('tgDataBase.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute(
        'CREATE TABLE users (id int auto_increment primary key,name varchar(50),pass varchar(50),phone varchar(50))')

    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет. Давай начнём регистрацию!\nДля начала введи своё имя')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_name)


def user_name(message):
    global name
    name = message.text.strip()

    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите номер телефона')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_phone)

def user_phone(message):
    global phone
    phone = message.text.strip()


    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите пароль')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, user_pass)


def user_pass(message):
    password = message.text.strip()

    conn = sqlite3.connect('tgDataBase.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, pass, phone) VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s')" % (name, password, phone))

    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    markup.add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Список пользователей', callback_data='users'))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Пользователь зарегистрирован!', reply_markup=markup)



@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback(call):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('tgDataBase.sql')
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users')

    users = cur.fetchall()

    info = ''
    for el in users:
        info += f'Имя: {el[1]}, Пароль: {el[2]}, Номер Телефона: {el[3]}\n'

    cur.close()
    conn.close()

    bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, info)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Вот как после получения данных - делать так чтобы при необходимости я могу отправить одно сообщение и оно пришло всем кто есть в списке sqlite ?